# Don't stop multithreading/start a thread when one die

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi i'd like to know how never stop a multithreading Java application. Threads die if an Exception in the run method is caught, can I avoid that?
If not, can i know when one of my threads die and then I can start another one?

This is the main

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) 
        { 
            MyClass object = new MyClass();
            Thread myThread = new Thread(object); 
            myThread.start();
        }
```

this is MyClass which implements runnable

```
 @Override
public void run() {
    try {
        theLoopMethod();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error: check errors.txt");
   }
```

Comment: Use a `ThreadPool` and an `Executor`, which are [high-level concurrency objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer question 1:

*Threads die if an Exception in the run method is caught, can I avoid that?*

You can wrap the code in a endless while loop or actually fix your code so that the exception is not thrown.

```
while (true) {
    try {
        theLoopMethod();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("error: check errors.txt");
   }
}
```